# frida cant cast string array to java.lang.object

Tags: android, java, frida

i have a java method i am trying to call manually

`public static native Object a(int i, int i2, long j, String str, Object obj);`

the last parameter is a string list casted to java.lang.object the way java code does it is by using the `arraylist.toArray(new String[0])` which returns a `"<instance: java.lang.Object, $className: [Ljava.lang.String;>"` i tried every single way to replicate this variable using frida and i failed

this is the code i tried

```
var s = Java.array("java.lang.String", ["e"])
var k = Java.cast(s, Java.use("java.lang.Object"))
```

this results in

```
Error: expected a pointer
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/env.js:165)
    at apply (native)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/env.js:97)
    at cast (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:131)
    at cast (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:270)
    at <anonymous> (/frida/repl-2.js:25)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:12)
    at _performPendingVmOps (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:250)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:225)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:12)
    at _performPendingVmOpsWhenReady (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:244)
    at perform (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:204)
    at <anonymous> (/frida/repl-2.js:186)
```

i also tried this

```
var e = ["a"]
const arrayList = Java.use("java.util.ArrayList")
const arr = arrayList.$new()
for (var i = 0; i <= e.length; i++){
    if (e[i]){
        arr.add(e[i]);
    }
}
var s = arr.toArray()
```

which returns `["<instance: java.lang.Object, $className: java.lang.String>","<instance: java.lang.Object, $className: java.lang.String>"]`

this casts every single element in the array to a java.lang.object instead of the array object itself when i pass this to the method as a parameter i get the same error as above `Error: expected a pointer`

i also tried passing a `Java.array("java.lang.String", [])` to `.toArray()` method and it raises the same error

1)is there a way to call this method using frida??

2)can i create a .so library with a function that casts my array to java.lang.object and inject it into the app or something along these lines?

Comment: Have you considered that this could be a bug? I would oben up an issue in the Frida issue tracker to make sure. And make sure you are latest frida version on Android and PC.